# i:Interaction.Triggers is not working in Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I added

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

namespace but it is showing error.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>   
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnter}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

In WP8.1 you should use this :

```
 <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoaded}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

with

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

You can find missing dll here :

- On right click "Add Reference"
- Open Windows 8.1 or WindowsPhone 8.1
- Open Extensions
- Select Behaviors SDK (XAML)

Answer (score 2):

There simply is no `MouseEnter` event, when there's no mouse cursor. You'll have to use some other event to trigger your command.